# Cannot add migration in .NET Core using CLI

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have experience to use EF migrations in .NET MVC but after switching to .NET Core and CLI, now I cannot apply migrations using CLI. Here are the commands that I use, but I am not sure in which project I should open CLI.

Assume that I open CLI on the solution directory and there are 2 projects; Domain project contains Entities, and Infrastructure project contains Migrations folder:

***add-migration***

```
dotnet ef migrations add AddDateOfBirthField --project src\Domain 
--context ApplicationDbContext --output-dir src\Infrastructure\Migrations
```

Throws the following error:

*Startup project 'Domain.csproj' targets framework '.NETStandard'. There is no runtime associated with this framework, and projects targeting it cannot be executed directly. To use the Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools with this project, add an executable project targeting .NET Core or .NET Framework that references this project, and set it as the startup project using --startup-project; or, update this project to cross-target .NET Core or .NET Framework. For more information on using the Entity Framework Tools with .NET Standard projects, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2034781*

So, should I execute the command from another directory of CLI or use an extra flag e.g. `--startup-project`?

Comment: Does anybody else have no experience with `Entity Framework Core`?

Comment: `--project src\Domain` type is not .Net Core or .Net framework. That's why you are getting this error.

Comment: This should help - https://rajbos.github.io/blog/2020/04/23/EntityFramework-Core-NET-Standard-Migrations

Comment: @Berkay Thanks amigo. How should I run that command? Could you post it according to the given info (*Domain project contains Entities, and Infrastructure project contains Migrations folder:*)

Comment: @Yogi Perfect !!! Many thanks amigo, it seems to be working.

Comment: Glad it helped @zertuc. Written it as an answer so that it could be of help to others.

Comment: @Berkay Amigo?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get this issue with using the Entity Framework Core tools in a .NET Standard Library: the EF Core tools don’t support the .NET Standard framework: they can only target .NET Core or .NET Classic (Full framework). To resolve this you need to create a dummy project with a dependency on the .NET Standard Library. You can find more details [here](https://rajbos.github.io/blog/2020/04/23/EntityFramework-Core-NET-Standard-Migrations) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#other-target-frameworks).

Comment: For me, the only thing that I should do is to add `--project` and `--startup-project` flags.

Comment: Should I use --output-dir flag in order o point Migration folder?

Comment: @zertuc This will be the directory to put entity class files in. So if you want to change the directory you can specify this flag, otherwise skip this.

Comment: But while the `dbContext` and `entity class` files are on different projects, how could EF Core infer it? Because the `--project` flag only points the project where `dbContext` and Migrations are kept. ANy idea?

Comment: @zertuc Yes EF will infer it according to the references. Here is a link for the EF Core CLI commands for complete details. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet